How to create vpc endpoints for aws opensearch via terraform?
I have set up an opensearch instance, see sample code below, via terraform. I have added a vpc_options configuration in my terraform code. this works but , i would like to know , is it possible to create a vpc endpoint for my opensearch instance via terraform? In addition, i'm also looking for any examples , on how to set up a user with master_user_name and master_user_password via terraform?
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "test" {
  domain_name           = "osi-example-domain"
  engine_version = "OpenSearch_2.7"
  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "r5.large.search"
  }
  vpc_options {
    subnet_ids = [
      data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids[0],
      data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids[1],
    ]

    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.example.id]
  }
  encrypt_at_rest {
    enabled = true
  }
  domain_endpoint_options {
    enforce_https       = true
    tls_security_policy = "Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07"
  }
  node_to_node_encryption {
    enabled = true
  }
  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
  }
 access_policies = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "${aws_iam_role.example.arn}"
      },
      "Action": "es:*"
    }
  ]
}

EOF

}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name        = "securitygroup-opensearch}"
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.example.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
    protocol  = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = [
      data.aws_vpc.example.cidr_block,
    ]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "example" {
  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.example.id

  tags = {
    Tier = "private"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "exampleosisrole"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "osis-pipelines.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

